# ES6 classes: different ways of writing, same output

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, super

I created the Class Vehicle, and extended it with Class Car. However in extending the Class, I obtained the same output using different ways of writing constructor() and super() - see cases 1 to 4. Could someone help me in spotting the differences?

These are my conclusion insofar:

- Case 1 and Case 2 are identical. When omitting constructor () and super (), by default the system includes them in running the code, passing all arguments from child to parent class.
- In Case 3, I instantiate the Car class, passing "Mercedes" as a value, while "car" overrides the `type` variable in the Car class . This means that if I instantiate the Car class a second time, and this time pass "Volvo" as a value, the result will be

```
   let car = new Car('Volvo');
   console.log(car.getName() ); // This is the car's name: Volvo
   console.log(car.getType() ); // car
```

- In Case 4, I instantiate the Car class, overriding with two values ('Mercedes' and 'car', both the `name` and the `type` variables in the Car class . As a result, if I instantiate the Car class, this time passing "Volvo" and "moto" as values, the console.log result will still show Merceds and car:

```
   let car = new Car('Volvo', 'moto');
   console.log(car.getName() ); // This is the car's name: Mercedes
   console.log(car.getType() ); // car
```

#### Class

```
    class Vehicle {
      constructor (name, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
      }
      getName () {
        return this.name;
      }
      getType () {
        return this.type;
      }
    }
```

#### Extends - Case 1

```
    class Car extends Vehicle {
      getName () {
        return "This is the car's name: " + super.getName();
      }
    }

    let car = new Car('Mercedes', 'car');
    console.log( car.getName() ); // This is the car's name: Mercedes
    console.log( car.getType() ); // car
```

#### Extends - Case 2

```
    class Car extends Vehicle {
      constructor (name, type) {
        super(name, type);
      }
      getName () {
        return "This is the car's name: " + super.getName();
      }
    }

    let car = new Car('Mercedes', 'car');
    console.log( car.getName() ); // This is the car's name: Mercedes
    console.log( car.getType() ); // car
```

#### Extends - Case 3

```
    class Car extends Vehicle {
      constructor (name) {
        super(name, 'car');
      }
      getName () {
        return "This is the car's name: " + super.getName();
      }
    }

    let car = new Car('Mercedes');
    console.log( car.getName() ); // This is the car's name: Mercedes
    console.log( car.getType() ); // car
```

#### Extends - Case 4

```
    class Car extends Vehicle {
      constructor (name) {
        super('Mercedes', 'car');
      }
      getName () {
        return "This is the car's name: " + super.getName();
      }
    }

    let car = new Car;
    console.log( car.getName() ); // This is the car's name: Mercedes
    console.log( car.getType() ); // car
```

Comment: You already did a pretty good explanation. What is your question?

Comment: @clayton.carmo I reached these conclusions, but I wanted to have a more expert view on them to validate them. Is everything I wrote correct? I'm doing my best to put solid foundations. Are there any differences I didn't spot and may affect the way I write future more complex code?

Comment: You did a good job. Your examples and conclusions are correct.